# Exception occured while using (Intent.ACTION_VIEW) in my program

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am writing a code to open Browser. But when i m running the program it shows Activity not found . Is It necessary to declare activity in Mainfest file , when i use `Intent.Action_VIEW,Uri` Code in my Program?

I have dont lot of R & D on google but not able to find the solution. Please help. The code is following. What i should do to recover this problem.

```
private void openBrowser() {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlText.getText().toString());
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should add your activity to your manifest! And if you use an external link you should also add internet access rights to your manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you type in the textbox. Try with http://www.google.com. It worked for me.  From your comment it seems you typed google.com instead of http://www.google.com. Try this!!!

Comment: Thanks Sweety...its working.. Actually i have taken input through ui edittext box. when i pass google.com.. error comes but when i write  http://www.google.com.   its move to the google page in browser.. .Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`
Should be declared in androidManifest.xml

Comment: i have write internet permission in mainfeast file. but exception is in activity start time. Exception is following :  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=google.com }

Answer (score 0):

I created a "HelloWorld" app and the VIEW_ACTION Uri code works fine in it, so I don't think the "Activity not found" error has anything to do with it or the permissions. You should check if you have added your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
package org.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "http://www.google.com/";
                browseWebPage(url);
            }});
    }

    public void browseWebPage(final String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

}
```

Regards

Ziteng Chen